# Unknown query using up RDS (Postgres) resources

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

Looking the queries using up resources for my Postgres RDS I keep seeing this query, which is not in our codebase

`select oid, typelem from pg_catalog.pg_type where typcategory = ?`

I haven't found any documentation on this, what could be triggering this to be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a query I would expect to be called by things like GUIs and ORMs which try to introspect into the database, so they know how to populate things like tab-completion or drop-down boxes or how to interpret data retrieved from the database for user-defined types.

What are you seeing that makes you think it uses up your resources?